# Cocos2dx 3.0 Failed ..build_native.py ( Build to Android)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

cpp

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
extern
"C"
{
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_cppSum(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
    {
        MessageBox( "Call me From Java11", "JNI Test11" );

        HelloWorld::doFiring(); //I wan't excute.....
        log("CCCCCCCCCCC");
        return 121;
    }
}
#endif

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();   
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void HelloWorld::doFiring()
{
    MessageBox( "Call me From Java11", "JNI Test11" );
}
```

Build to this page ..
Error Message:

[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp: In function 'jint Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_cppSum(JNIEnv*, jobject)':
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:19:24: error: cannot call member function 'void HelloWorld::doFiring()' without ob
ject
   HelloWorld::doFiring();
                        ^
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/**/**/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o] Error 1

.

Comment: sounds like doFiring is not declared static but is a member function, yet you call it like a static class method: HelloWorld::doFiring()

Answer (score 0):

HelloWorld::doFiring() isn't a static function.
you can call 
    Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene();
to get scene,then found the child which have do fire function.
maybe your code should like:

```
auto children = Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->getChildren();
for(auto child:children)
{
    auto layer = dynamic_cast<HelloWorld*>(child);
    if (layer) {
        layer.doFiring();
    }
}
```